# Make a named list of pairwise locations of a dataframe rows in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, lapply

In my `data` below, I was wondering how to make a named list of pairwise locations (i.e., `row number`) of a dataframe rows in R?

Specifically, I want to do pairwise comparison of every 3 rows. For example, in my `Desired_output`, you'll see that I have manually done so for the first 6 rows.

For the first 3 rows in my `Desired_output`, I compare `third row - first row` whose row numbers are `c(3, - 1)`. Then, I compare `third row - second row` whose row numbers are `c(3, - 2)`. And then, I compare `second row - first row` whose row numbers are `c(2, - 1)`.

Can we possibly automate this to obtain my desired output below?

```
Desired_output =

list("4.100 - 1.700 (c2s,complex,t1)"=c(3,-1),
     "4.100 - 2.900 (c2s,complex,t1)"=c(3,-2),
     "2.900 - 1.700 (c2s,complex,t1)"=c(2,-1),
     
     "4.100 - 1.700 (s2c,complex,t2)"=c(6,-4),
     "4.100 - 2.900 (s2c,complex,t2)"=c(6,-5),
     "2.900 - 1.700 (s2c,complex,t2)"=c(5,-4),
     
     .
     .
     .
)
```

```
data = read.table(h=TRUE, text = "
     Measure    motiv   t   ord task_df 
1   ac_EFC/C    1.700   1   c2s complex 
2   ac_EFC/C    2.900   1   c2s complex 
3   ac_EFC/C    4.100   1   c2s complex 

4   ac_EFC/C    1.700   2   s2c complex 
5   ac_EFC/C    2.900   2   s2c complex 
6   ac_EFC/C    4.100   2   s2c complex 

7   ac_EFC/C    1.700   3   c2s complex 
8   ac_EFC/C    2.900   3   c2s complex 
9   ac_EFC/C    4.100   3   c2s complex 

10  ac_EFC/C    1.700   4   s2c complex 
11  ac_EFC/C    2.900   4   s2c complex 
12  ac_EFC/C    4.100   4   s2c complex 

13  ac_EFC/C    1.700   1   s2c simple  
14  ac_EFC/C    2.900   1   s2c simple  
15  ac_EFC/C    4.100   1   s2c simple  
    
16  ac_EFC/C    1.700   2   c2s simple  
17  ac_EFC/C    2.900   2   c2s simple  
18  ac_EFC/C    4.100   2   c2s simple  

19  ac_EFC/C    1.700   3   s2c simple  
20  ac_EFC/C    2.900   3   s2c simple  
21  ac_EFC/C    4.100   3   s2c simple  

22  ac_EFC/C    1.700   4   c2s simple  
23  ac_EFC/C    2.900   4   c2s simple  
24  ac_EFC/C    4.100   4   c2s simple")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `combn` after grouping - create a sequence column `rn`, then concatenate the 'ord', 'task_df', 't' columns to  create a grouping column 'grp', grouped by the column, apply `combn` on the 'motiv' to return a pairwise combination of elements, paste (`str_c`) them, as well as create a pairwise index from the 'rn', created, `unite` the 'val', 'grp' columns and the set the names of the list column 'ind' with 'val'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(grp = sprintf('(%s,%s,t%s)', ord, task_df, t)) %>%
  group_by(grp = factor(grp, levels = unique(grp)) ) %>% 
  # or use summarise, but reframe will be preferred when the number
  # of rows are expanded
  reframe(val = combn(motiv, 2, 
    FUN = \(x) str_c(x[2], ' - ', x[1])),
       ind = combn(rn, 2, \(x) c(x[2], -x[1]), simplify = FALSE)) %>% 
  unite(val, val, grp, sep = " ") %>%
  with(., setNames(ind, val))
```

-output

```
`2.9 - 1.7 (c2s,complex,t1)`
[1]  2 -1

$`4.1 - 1.7 (c2s,complex,t1)`
[1]  3 -1

$`4.1 - 2.9 (c2s,complex,t1)`
[1]  3 -2

$`2.9 - 1.7 (s2c,complex,t2)`
[1]  5 -4

$`4.1 - 1.7 (s2c,complex,t2)`
[1]  6 -4

$`4.1 - 2.9 (s2c,complex,t2)`
[1]  6 -5

$`2.9 - 1.7 (c2s,complex,t3)`
[1]  8 -7

$`4.1 - 1.7 (c2s,complex,t3)`
[1]  9 -7

$`4.1 - 2.9 (c2s,complex,t3)`
[1]  9 -8

$`2.9 - 1.7 (s2c,complex,t4)`
[1]  11 -10

$`4.1 - 1.7 (s2c,complex,t4)`
[1]  12 -10

$`4.1 - 2.9 (s2c,complex,t4)`
[1]  12 -11

$`2.9 - 1.7 (s2c,simple,t1)`
[1]  14 -13

$`4.1 - 1.7 (s2c,simple,t1)`
[1]  15 -13

$`4.1 - 2.9 (s2c,simple,t1)`
[1]  15 -14

$`2.9 - 1.7 (c2s,simple,t2)`
[1]  17 -16

$`4.1 - 1.7 (c2s,simple,t2)`
[1]  18 -16

$`4.1 - 2.9 (c2s,simple,t2)`
[1]  18 -17

$`2.9 - 1.7 (s2c,simple,t3)`
[1]  20 -19

$`4.1 - 1.7 (s2c,simple,t3)`
[1]  21 -19

$`4.1 - 2.9 (s2c,simple,t3)`
[1]  21 -20

$`2.9 - 1.7 (c2s,simple,t4)`
[1]  23 -22

$`4.1 - 1.7 (c2s,simple,t4)`
[1]  24 -22

$`4.1 - 2.9 (c2s,simple,t4)`
[1]  24 -23
```

Comment: I made the above function out of your solution but it looks like when I do:`foo(data)`  the `combn()` call doesn't recognize the `effect_of` argument.

Comment: `foo <- function(data, effect_of = "motiv"){
  data %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number(), !!effect_of := ifelse(!!effect_of==max(!!effect_of),"High", ifelse(!!effect_of==min(!!effect_of),"Low", "Medium"))) %>% 
    mutate(grp = sprintf('(%s,%s,t%s)', ord, task_df, t)) %>%
    group_by(grp = factor(grp, levels = unique(grp)) ) %>% 
    summarise(val = combn(!!effect_of, 2, 
                          FUN = \(x) str_c(x[2], ' - ', x[1])),
              ind = combn(rn, 2, \(x) c(x[2], -x[1]), simplify=FALSE)) %>% 
    unite(val, val, grp, sep=" ") %>%
    with(., setNames(ind, val))}`

Comment: @rnorouzian the rhs could be `!! rlang::sym(effect_of)`